# How to include an artifact from one Gradle project as a resource in another project?

Tags: gradle

Given a project file structure like this:

```
git-root
 ├── ServerApp
 │    ├── build.gradle
 │    └── src
 │        └── ...
 └── ClientJAR
     ├── build.gradle
     └── src
         └── ...
```

`ServerApp` needs to include an artifact of `ClientJAR`'s build (the default artifact) as one of its resources. There is no *dependency* between `ServerApp` and `ClientJAR` in the traditional sense - neither project references code from the other.

As the diagram shows, the two Gradle projects are *siblings* in a single git repo. Changing that structure (eg, to make this a container/composite build) is only a last resort; I'm looking for a solution that keeps this structure intact.

**Some Background/Context**

The intention is that the application built by `ServerApp` has an endpoint that can be used to download the artifact that was built in `ClientJAR` project. The most obvious way (to me) to implement that is to have `ClientJAR`'s artifact be embedded into `ServerApp` (which is a Spring Boot application) as a resource at build time.

I've tried using `includeFlat` and declaring `ClientJAR` as a dependency in `ServerApp`, but that caused the "plain" `ClientJAR` JAR artifact to be included in `ServerApp`'s libs, which isn't what I need. I need the bootJar artifact (which is currently the result of calling `gradlew build` in `ClientJAR`).

Is there a clean way to "embed" a sibling like this? Even a concrete example of one build invoking another (sibling) and then copying its output into the `/build/resources` folder would be a reasonable option (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Link the build of the projects together so they can reference one another;
2. Obtain the desired JAR in the `ServerApp` build by depending on a `ClientJAR` configuration; and
3. Copy the JAR to the location it needs to be in resources.

##### 1. Link the build of the projects together

As you have already done, you can achieve this with the use of `includeFlat`:

```
// ServerApp/settings.gradle

includeFlat("ClientJAR")
```

##### 2. Obtain the JAR in the consuming project via new configurations

Gradle have [instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#cross_project_publications) for sharing artifacts in this way. To summarise, you can do it in four steps:

(a) Add a new consumable configuration to the producer project (`ClientJAR`):

```
// ClientJAR/build.gradle

configurations {
   bootJarConsumable {
      canBeConsumed = true
      canBeResolved = false
   }
}
```

(b) Add the desired artifact to it, using the [Jar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.html) task which generates `bootJar` (assumed called `bootJarTaskName`):

```
// ClientJAR/build.gradle

artifacts {
   bootJarConsumable(tasks.named('bootJarTaskName'))
}
```

(c) Add a new configuration to `ServerJAR` for loading the JAR

```
// ServerApp/build.gradle

configurations {
   bootJarResolvable {
      canBeConsumed = false
      canBeResolved = true
   }
}
```

(d) Depend on the artifact in consuming project by depending on the new configuration:

```
// ServerApp/build.gradle

dependencies {
   bootJarResolvable project(path: ':ClientJAR', configuration: 'bootJarConsumable')
}
```

##### 3. Copy the JAR to the location it needs to be in resources

`ServerApp` then has access to the JAR, but it is not in the desired location. You can write a task to do the final copy step:

```
// ServerApp/build.gradle

tasks.register('copyToResources', Copy) {
    from configurations.named('bootJarResolvable')
    into sourceSets.main.resources.sourceDirectories.singleFile
}
```

Finally, you need to ensure the `processResources` task depends on this so all everything will run when the `ServerApp` build is run:

```
// ServerApp/build.gradle

processResources {
    dependsOn copyToResources
}
```

Comment: Will that result in `ClientJAR`'s artifact being included *as a library* in `ServerApp` (ie, in the `lib` folder)? Doing so will make the job of serving it from an ServerApp endpoint somewhat harder as it's non-standard to read libs as resources.

Comment: I'd overlooked how vital that was to you. Now updated to add a final step to copy the JAR to where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still testing and checking, but here is what I got working using a combination of custom `GradleBuild` and `Copy` tasks.

In `ServerApp` I added these custom tasks:

```
task buildClient(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = '../ClientJAR/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['clean', 'build']
}

task copyClient(type: Copy, dependsOn: buildClient) {
    from ('../ClientJAR/build/libs/') {
        include 'client-*.jar'
        rename { 'client.jar' }
    }
    into "$buildDir/resources/main"
}
```

I also declared that `processResources` should depend on `copyClient`:

```
processResources {
    dependsOn copyClient
}
```

With that, `client.jar` ends up in `ServerApp/build/resources/main/` (and in the final Boot WAR artifact) as expected.

Comment: You should really **never** do something like this. Do not use `GradleBuild`, it is old and discouraged and also not compatible with composite builds besides totally the wrong tool here. You should almost never use  `Copy` but in most cases `Sync`. You should never declare explicit task dependencies except with a lifecycle task on the left-hand side. You should never have overlapping outputs of tasks like when writing to the output directory of another task.

Comment: @Vampire can you provide links to documentation about your claims of "never?" Or at least some explanations? Perhaps a chat room if it gets lengthy...

Comment: For the explicit task deps, they are always a codesmell. You should wire task outputs to inputs and thus get necessary task dependencies automatically where necessary. With explicit task dependencies you can forget to remove them when no longer needed, and you can forget to add them to all places where necessary if you actually are able to find all. If you for example have a task that generates sources and just make the compilation task depend on it, static analysis tasks, source jar tasks, and all other tasks needing sources miss that task dependency and miss the sources or use stale ones.

Comment: For the overlapping outputs, you majorly disturb Gradle optimizations with that. It for example disturbs up-to-date checks. Or for cacheable tasks it can also cause wrong cache entries to be stored or restored and so on. Tasks should never have overlapping outputs, including modifying the output files of a different task.

Comment: How to properly do this (Simon's answer is also not really good for similar reasons as mentioned here) depends on more details you did not provide. For example, is `ServerApp` and `ClientJar` separate standalone builds with own settings script? Then you should never ever ever ever do `include` or `includeFlat` one from the other, as a project should always only be added to exactly one build, or you earn much problems. In that case, you would use composite build instead and you do not need to change the direcotry layout as you wrote that is not really an option due to that.

Comment: Lots of stuff in there that sounds somewhat idealistic, but some perhaps meaningful in my context. Can you provide an answer with a concrete example that doesn't require a composite build?

Comment: It is not just idealistic, your build is simply buggy, flaky, and unreliable if you do it like that. But hey, it's your build, do whatever fits for you. :-) And no, I cannot provide an example. I already said you provided not enough information, for example whether those are standalone builds with own settings scripts, or already projects of the same multi-project build for example.

Comment: The two projects and their builds are completely independent other than living in the same git repo. I think the structure "diagram" shows that, but now i've stated it unequivocally. An example would be helpful to understand the overhead needed to eliminate any inconsistent behavior potential; assume no further dependence or structure than what I've described. Also, under what circumstances would my solution behave flaky or unreliable?

Comment: The "diagram" does not show it, as it does not show where you have settings scripts, just where you have build scripts and thus it could be either way. But now that you stated that those builds are independent builds, you really should not `include` or `includeFlat` one from the other. Assuming both builds are using the same Gradle version, what is the reason you do not want to use a composite build?

Comment: My limitations are that I can't (unless there's no option) alter the existing project structure, and that the `bootJar` artifact from `ClientJAR` end up in the resources of `ServerApp`. If a composite build can be made to satisfy those, I'd consider it as an alternative solution.

Comment: Sure, that's the whole point of a composite build. You include a whole other build and then depend on artifacts or plugins build in that other build like you would depend on a binary dependency. And if not, I would at least use the tooling API to drive the other build and just define the file as output of that task, configuring the task as resources srcdir instead of polluting the output directory of another task. I'll see whether I find the time to knit it together for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here a variant to solve it properly using a composite build:

In `settings.gradle.kts` of `ServerApp`:

```
includeBuild("../ClientJar")
```

In `build.gradle.kts` of `ServerApp`:

```
val clientJarBucket by configurations.dependencyScope("clientJarBucket")

dependencies {
    clientJarBucket("com.example:ClientJAR") {
        isTransitive = false
    }
}

val clientJar by configurations.resolvable("clientJar") {
    extendsFrom(clientJarBucket)
}

val syncClientJar by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
    from(clientJar)
    into(temporaryDir)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir(syncClientJar)
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here a variant to solve it properly using the tooling API, though I would probably prefer the more integrated approach above, for example it can be better up-to-date, by driving another build you practically always have to run it fully:

In `build.gradle.kts` of `ServerApp`:

```
val buildClientJar by tasks.registering {
    outputs.dir(temporaryDir)
    doLast {
        GradleConnector
            .newConnector()
            .forProjectDirectory(file("../ClientJAR"))
            .connect()
            .use {
                it
                    .newBuild()
                    .forTasks("jar")
                    .setStandardOutput(System.out)
                    .setStandardError(System.err)
                    .run()
            }
        sync {
            from("../ClientJAR/build/libs/ClientJAR.jar")
            into(temporaryDir)
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir(buildClientJar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to digest this but we're not using the kotlin DSL, we're using Groovy (and I don't speak Kotlin :-)

Comment: Except for `val` and `by` it should practically be the same, I believe you will be able to adapt in Groovy DSL. But you should really consider switching. By now the Kotlin DSL is the default DSL, you immediately get type-safe build scripts, actually helpful error messages if you mess up the syntax, and an amazingly better IDE support when using a good IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.